# $\int_E|f − φ| < ε$, $\int_E|f − ψ| < ε$, $\int_E|f − g| < ε$.

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f$ be an integrable function over $E$. Then given $ε > 0$, there is a simple function $φ$, step function $ψ$, and a continuous function $g$ supported on a finite measure set such that   
$\int_E|f − φ| < ε$, $\int_E|f − ψ| < ε$, $\int_E|f − g| < ε$.

How to prove it? I am not getting any hint.

Comment: I don't know any book about measure and integration that doesn't prove these results...

Comment: Okay then give me one referrence..

Comment: page 71 (thm 2.4): http://www.cmat.edu.uy/~mordecki/courses/medida2013/book.pdf